# Swap to Increase RAM but kernel issue

Tags: kernel, swap

I have Micromax Canvas Doodle A111 phone with Android v4.1.2.
My phone has 512 MB RAM by default.
So whenever I try installing some new apps my phone becomes really slow so I decided to increase RAM by rooting.

However when I used swapper app to increase RAM, it shows kernel support required.

I don't know how to enable swapping feature for my device.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Is there a custom kernel for your device that supports a swap? If not, you can't do it (unless you can build a kernel, which is a very non-trivial task).

Comment: actually i could see only 3 or 4 custom roms for my device in xda forum. when that is the case, chance to find custom kernel is less. my results are " 0 found ".

Comment: Swap does not actually increase the RAM. [All about linux Swap](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space) - if you are thinking about using swap, I figured you should know what it is and what it does. The custom ROMs you mentioned may have a custom kernel with support, you should check the threads for them and/or ask the developers of the ROM.